# Cannot create angular component in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create an angular component in visual studio code. By default, my angular components are in ClientApp. I have some default components in ClientApp. When I tried to add a new angular component in the components folder in ClientApp I get an error.

When I enter "ng g component vehicle-form" I have an error. It says " Invalid path: "vehicle-form" cannot be above the "ClientApp\app" directory." However, my angular components are in the app folder located within the app folder of Client App.

> PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega> cd ClientApp
>   PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega\ClientApp> cd app
>   PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega\ClientApp\app> cd components
>   PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega\ClientApp\app\components> ng g component
>   vehicle-form
>   Invalid path: "vehicle-form" cannot be above the "ClientApp\app"
>   directory

My .angular-cli.json configuration  is as listed below.

```
"apps": [
        {
          "root": "ClientApp",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a component from angular cli then just run the command

```
  ng g component vehicle-form
```

From your root directory i.e

```
 PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega\ClientApp> ng g component vehicle-form
```

Comment: Tried it. still getting the same error.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                
PS C:\Users\Sushi\vega\ClientApp> ng g component vehicle-form               
Invalid path: "vehicle-form" cannot be above the "ClientApp\app" directory

Comment: Invalid path: "app/vehicle-form" cannot be above the "ClientApp\app" directory.    How is it above the "ClientApp\app" directory when I creating from within the ClientApp folder.

Comment: Whats your root directory ClientApp or vega, I recently taken a closer look and I think your root directory is vega then you must run angular commands from vega

Comment: When I try to create a module from Vega, this is the error that is shown. Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.

Comment: Name of the project is Vega and the root of my angular component is ClientApp, there is where all the other angular components are located.

Comment: what is the location of your app.module.ts?

Comment: The app.module.ts is located in the app folder. When I click on the app folder, it shows a component folder and the app.module.ts (not inside the component folder). The app folder is  located in the ClientApp folder.

Comment: Unexpected behaviour, never seen before, then you must use ng g component vehicle-form --skip-import from Vega and then manually import to module

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
 "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
```

then ng g c vehicle-form